# How to properly create outline around image using RGB values?

Tags: arrays, image-processing, octave

I have an image that I import into Octave 5.2, and I would like to create an outline all the way around the image array using RGB values.

I'm having trouble inserting the RGB values back into the array correctly, inserting / generating the two rows at top, two columns on the left, two columns on the right, and two rows on the bottom all the way around the image / converted `double` array.

Example of original image:

[image: original]

Example of the image I'm trying to get when done:

[image: final image]

My logic was:

1. To convert the image to a `double` array so I can do math / insert the RGB values where I wanted them.
2. Insert the RGB values into the left, right, top, bottom of the array.
3. Convert the `double` array back to `uint8` to export / view it as image.

My code so far:

```
pkg load image
   
img_fn=('https://i.imgur.com/KKxJaOy.png'); %original image

f=imread(img_fn);
[im_r im_c]=size(f);
size_min=min(im_r,im_c); %get minum size from row and col
    
f_double=double(f); %need to convert to double to do math functions on it
    
outline_left_of_box=repmat(255,[rows(f_double),2]); %Create left line array of outline red box
f_double_tmp_red(:,:,1)=[outline_left_of_box,f_double];%Create left line of outline red box

red_outline_right_of_box=repmat(255,[rows(f_double),2]); %Create right line array of outline red box

red_outline_top_of_box=repmat(255,[2,columns(f_double)]); %Create top line array of outline red box

red_outline_bottom_of_box=repmat(255,[2,columns(f_double)]); %Create bottom line array of outline red box
    
%convert back to image
red_outline_img=uint8(f_double);

imshow(red_outline_img);  %used to show image in octave plot window
```

Please note: I'm converting the image array into a `double` because calculations will be done on the array to get the desired color box around the image, but I'm just trying to get the inserting RGB values into the array issue fixed first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's easier to simply paste the inner part of the input image onto some "background" image with the desired border color, like so:

```matlab
pkg load image

% Read image, get dimensions, convert to double
f = imread('https://i.imgur.com/KKxJaOy.png');
[im_ro, im_co, im_ch] = size(f);
f_double = double(f);

% Set up width and color of border
bw = 2;
color = ones(1, 1, im_ch);
color(1, 1, :) = [255, 0, 0];

% Create image of same size as input with solid color, and paste inner part of input
red_outline_img = ones(im_ro, im_co, im_ch) .* color;
red_outline_img(bw+1:end-bw, bw+1:end-bw, :) = f_double(bw+1:end-bw, bw+1:end-bw, :);
red_outline_img = uint8(red_outline_img);
imshow(red_outline_img);
```

That'd be the output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks!  "There's all-ways another way to skin a cat"

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could try is plot the lines as you suggest, which can be done very efficiently with some clever use of `xlim`/`ylim`, and then print the whole thing as an -RGBImage to get it back in image form.

The only caveat here though is that you will need to play with the formatting options to get what you're really after (e.g. in case you want higher or lower resolution), since you really are printing what's on your screen at this point.

E.g.

```
L = imread('leaf.png');
imshow(L)
hold on
plot( [xlim, fliplr(xlim);xlim, xlim], [ylim, ylim;fliplr(ylim), ylim], 'r', 'linewidth', 2 )
hold off
set( gca, 'position', [0, 0, 1, 1] );
set( gcf, 'paperposition', [0, 0, 1, 1] );
R = print( '-RGBImage' );
close
imshow(R); set( gcf, 'color', 'k'); axis off
```